# PLINK is stuck at an older host - how do I replace it?

Tags: putty, plink

For some reason, when I issue PLINK.EXE by itself (no command line parameters) it *always* tries to connect to some remote host which I used in the past but I no longer use now.

How do I change it to **default** to a different host?

(I know about the `-l hostname` option but this isn't what I am interested in my particular situation)

**UPDATE:** Could this be related to [the PuTTY cmdline-host-override bug](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/cmdline-host-override.html)?

Regardless, I need to find a way to workaround this. I can't recall how that older host got there in the first place, but there's got to be a way to change it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

Thanks to [section 4.1.2 Loading and storing saved sessions](http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-saving):

1. Open PuTTY Configuration
2. Click the `Default Settings` line under "Saved Settings"
3. Click the `Load` button
4. Edit the `Host Name (or IP address)` edit box to change from the
   older host to the one you want.
5. Click the `Save` button.

Done.

Comment: Nice, was not aware of that feature ;) If you are using Git, check out git-flow for advanced usage.

Comment: ssvnc uses plink, having any not-blank default settings set in putty causes ssvnc to ignore the user's given host and instead connects to the default settings... clearing default settings made it work again.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the command-line help for PLINK.EXE v0.60. [See full version here](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

```
PuTTY Link: command-line connection utility
Release 0.60
Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
       ("host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)
```

Notice that you need to supply a hostname in order to run PLINK.EXE. So i am guessing you are clicking on a shortcut instead, which has been set up to run PLINK.EXE with a specific hostname.

Comment: Thanks. I am **not** running a shortcut. I double-click `C:\Program Files (x86)\putty\PLINK.EXE` and immediately receive a prompt `login as: ` from that old host. There's got to be a way to replace it.

Comment: BTW, the first paragraph in [7.1 Starting Plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) is completely wrong. I *am* able to double-click on its icon to run it. See earlier comment.

Comment: On Windows 7 i have Putty installed and i do not see any link to PLINK.EXE. Before you click, try instead to right-click and select properties. Check that the target is pointing to PLINK.EXE.

Comment: It's **not** a link. This is 100% verified. It's an Application(.EXE) having the size of 282,624 bytes. Please note that I cannot use command line parameters because it needs to be used with `git` as described here: http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html